# How to face extraction from images in a folder with MTCNN in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I want to extract the faces from images in a folder—there are approximately 8000 images—with mtcnn in Python. I must also save the new images to a file. How could I do this? I use Jupyter notebook on GPU.
If there are multiple faces in the image, what kind of path should I follow?

Answer (score 3):

the function below will read an image located at image_path and attempt to crop the image.
If the image has more than 1 face in it the function will return the cropped image of the largest size face in the image. If no face is detected in the image the function will return status as false and the image as None. You must have tensorflow installed in your environment.

```
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
def crop_image(image_path):
    detector = MTCNN() 
    img=cv2.imread(image_path)
    data=detector.detect_faces(img)
    biggest=0
    if data !=[]:
        for faces in data:
            box=faces['box']            
            # calculate the area in the image
            area = box[3]  * box[2]
            if area>biggest:
                biggest=area
                bbox=box 
        bbox[0]= 0 if bbox[0]<0 else bbox[0]
        bbox[1]= 0 if bbox[1]<0 else bbox[1]
        img=img[bbox[1]: bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]: bbox[0]+ bbox[2]] 
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert from bgr to rgb
        return (True, img) 
    else:
        return (False, None)
```

below is an example to use the function and display the cropped image

```
img_path=  # set this as the full path to the image you wish to crop
status,img=crop_image(img_path)
if status:
    plt.imshow(img)
else:
    print('No facial image was detected')
```

You can modify the function easily if you want to detect ALL the faces in an image

Answer (score 2):

To add to my previous answer here is a full solution. You must have mtcnn, cv2 and tensorflow installed.

```
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
import os
def crop_image(source_dir, dest_dir, mode):
    if os.path.isdir(dest_dir)==False:
        os.mkdir(dest_dir)
    detector = MTCNN()
    source_list=os.listdir(source_dir)
    uncropped_file_list=[]
    for f in source_list:
        f_path=os.path.join(source_dir, f)
        dest_path=os.path.join(dest_dir,f)
        img=cv2.imread(f_path)
        data=detector.detect_faces(img)
        if data ==[]:
            uncropped_file_list.append(f_path)
        else:
            if mode==1:  #detect the box with the largest area
                for i, faces in enumerate(data): # iterate through all the faces found
                    box=faces['box']  # get the box for each face                
                    biggest=0                    
                    area = box[3]  * box[2]
                    if area>biggest:
                        biggest=area
                        bbox=box 
                bbox[0]= 0 if bbox[0]<0 else bbox[0]
                bbox[1]= 0 if bbox[1]<0 else bbox[1]
                img=img[bbox[1]: bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]: bbox[0]+ bbox[2]] 
                cv2.imwrite(dest_path, img)
            else:
                for i, faces in enumerate(data): # iterate through all the faces found
                    box=faces['box']
                    if box !=[]:
                        # return all faces found in the image
                        box[0]= 0 if box[0]<0 else box[0]
                        box[1]= 0 if box[1]<0 else box[1]
                        cropped_img=img[box[1]: box[1]+box[3],box[0]: box[0]+ box[2]]
                        fname=os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                        fext=os.path.splitext(f)[1]
                        fname=fname + str(i) + fext
                        save_path=os.path.join(dest_dir,fname )
                        cv2.imwrite(save_path, cropped_img)  
       
    return uncropped_file_list
```

the source_dir is the full path to the directory containing the image files you want to crop. The dest_dir is the full  path to where you want to store the cropped images. If it does not exist the function creates it for you. Mode if set to 1  only  the single largest face cropped image in the image file is saved to the dest_dir. If mode is not set to 1 then for each image if there are multiple faces in the image all cropped faces in the image are saved to the dest_dir. In this case the saved file name in the dest_dir has the original file name appended with a numerical value. For example if the image file is named say nurses, and has 3 faces in the image then in the dest_dir there will be 3 images named nurses0, nurses1 and nurses2 associated with that file.  The function returns a list of file names of image files that were not cropped. NOTE MTCNN is not perfect and can make errors so check the cropped images visually. Also note the function does NOT return all the faces in an image if there are multiple faces in it. It returns the cropped image of the LARGEST face in the image. Shown below is example of use

```
source_dir=r'c:\temp\people\dummy' # directory with files to crop
dest_dir=r'c:\temp\people\results' # directory where cropped images get stored
uncropped_files_list=crop_image(source_dir, dest_dir,1) # mode=1 means 1 face per image
for f in uncropped_files_list:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Thak you for sharing. But I want to crop all images not only visible from the front profile but also side profils.

Comment: I do not think MTCNN can crop side profiles. I do not know of any available module that can but I will search around

Comment: @GerryP Is it possible to add a little more of the face to be included in the crop than usual.

Comment: yes in the code img=img[bbox[1]: bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]: bbox[0]+ bbox[2]]  change it to img=img[bbox[1]-e : bbox[1]+bbox[3]+e], bbox[0] -e: bbbox[0]+bbox[2]+e] where e is an integer representing number of additional pixels. I would get e from taking a percentage of the original images shape.